# Controller.MyMethod() doesn't kick off HttpModule, so how can I unit test an HttpModule?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, moq, asp.net-web-api2, httpmodule

How do I unit test a Web Api 2 HttpModule? The module checks for specific HTTP headers.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't kick off the HttpModule.

```
var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
var controller = new FeaturesV1Controller(logger.Object);
var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Add("X-My-Header", "success");
controllerContext.Request = request;
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext;

// Act
var result = controller.Get(11);
```

I've verified for real calls, that the HttpModule does get called.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about how to unit test a HttpModule [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/unit-testable-httpmodule-and-httphandler).

An alternative could be to not test the module itself but to move out the code that you want to test to another class. By injecting stuff into the request you’re not testing your code, you’re testing the framework. Unless that is what you want to test I would recommend you to move that code out from the HttpModule.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I provided two answers to the question: one link and one alternative to simply move the code to another class. The questions are questions that he should ask himself and I did not expect more info to be able to provide an answer. Will update the question to clarify.